# How do I delete intersecting geometry?

Tags: faces, geometry

I modelled a bunch of hair using Curves, and obviously, there's a lot of Vertices and Faces that I could go without, there's half a million Faces in the hair Mesh alone, and that's obviously too many Faces. How do I select the intersecting geometry? Select All by Trait > Interior Faces didn't work, it didn't even select any of the Mesh's Faces. I don't think I can just go into each orthographic view and select them by the sides.

Below is a MediaFire link, I can't find any way to select the intersecting geometry. If you can, please tell me.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/7g8xiedo1qbyeee/lwkris.blend/file

Comment: Do you mean "internal geometry" or "intersecting geometry"? Maybe it would help if you explain your question with a picture or share your blend file.

Comment: @quellenform Is there a difference between the two? I mean Faces that you can't see on the outside of the Mesh, only inside the Mesh.

Comment: "Internal Geometry" means geometry that is part of a mesh and lies within the structure. "Intersecting Geometry" means when two meshes intersect and one geometry extends into the other.

Comment: Is it work on [Merge By Distance]?

Comment: @XY I'm not sure what you mean by that. Are you asking if I've merged the vertices by distance yet?